# Between/Among and Which/Who

Tags: word-choice, questions, between-among

> Between the students in the class which is the best?

Is the above sentence correct grammatically? (My book says it is)

I presume we are using 'Between' instead of 'Among' although the question involves more than 2 people, as the comparison is between only two at each instance (Or am I wrong?)

But can 'which' be used here instead of 'who'?

Comment: Be careful of the "2/more than 2 rule". You can read a LOT about this at [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37636/between-vs-among/233385#233385), found at our sister site ELU.

Answer (score 1):

As the question that commenter @J.R. was kind enough to reference states, between is an appropriate word choice because it reflects the well-defined, individual nature of the relationship; there may be many students, but only one of them can be considered *the best*.

This is also the reason that both ***which*** and ***who*** can be used and still be grammatical. The word ***who*** refers to "the person that" or "the one that" and this parses just fine; as does the word ***which***, which refers to an individual person/thing among several of a class.